# Modal Não Retorna Banco de Dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, modal

Eu tenho uma tabela no banco de dados chamada patologias. Dentro desta tabela existe uma coluna chamada doenca. Eu criei um modal que deve retornar uma dropdownlist com todas as opções de doenças preenchidas na tabela nesta coluna para seleção do usuário. Entretanto o modal está retornando uma dropdownlist extamanet com o mesmo número de linhas da tabela porém vazios. Segue abaixo o código. Serei eternamente grato a quem ajudar. Estou travado a 4 dias neste problema:

conecta_mysql();

$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

```
<select name="doencaap1" required>
                    <option>Selecione...</option>
                    <?php while($prod = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $prod['doenca'] ?>"><option style = "color:red"></option>  
                     <?php } ?>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               Ja tentou com foreach ?

                 <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">CATEGORIA</option>
                        <?php foreach ($medics as $p): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $p->id; ?>" <?php
                            if (isset($_GET["category_id"]) && $_GET["category_id"] != "") {
                                echo "selected";
                            }
                            ?>><?php echo $p->name; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
```